# Does $f$ necessarily have infinte oscillations?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:(a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ does not exists($\neq \pm \infty$),then is it necessary that $f$ have infinitely many oscillations and therefore infinitely many local extrema's?

I think only way this can happen is to have infinitely many oscillations, but not sure.

Comment: A trivial counterexample is $f(z)=0$. So you need to exclude non-constant functions.

Comment: @Semiclassical: the function is required to not have a limit at $+\infty$, so these are already ruled out.

Comment: You're correct. Silly of me. @FPE

Comment: Hint: Can there exists a real $b$ such that $f$ is non-decreasing on $(b,+\infty)$? Similarly, can there exists a $c$ such that $f$ is non-increasing on $(c,+\infty)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there were only finitely many local extrema, then consider what happens after the last of them. The function will have to be monotonic after that point. Without loss of generality, assume it's increasing. If it's bounded then it converges and the limit exists. If it is unbounded then necessarily it has to go to infinity thus the limit exists again and is infinite. So the only way to have what you want is to have infinitely many local extrema.